# Easy way to turn JavaScript array into comma AND Quotation Marks separated string list?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know if there was a function that could turn an array into a string separated with Quotation Marks and commas in JS?

```js
var array = [1,2,3]

var result = '["1", "2", "3"]';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert array elements to strings, and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to get the resulting string:

```js
const array = [1,2,3];

const result = JSON.stringify(array.map(String));

console.log(result);
```